# Memory gap in Commodore PET

Tags: commodore, commodore-pet

Most largish programs written for the Commodore PET have a bunch of rem statements somewhere around the 8K or 16K area.  The normal comment is something to do with a hole in memory.  I remember PET programs crashing when I removed it.  I used the CBM 4032 and CBM 8032 but never tried removing the REM statements to see if the problem had been fixed.  Wish I had.

Two questions:

1. What is this memory gap?  Is it something like an address that has no memory?
2. Did this problem propagate to the CBM 4032, CBM 8032, VIC-20 and Commodore 64?

**Edit**

The other possibility is an overlap, where the address of the end of one chip overlapped with the address of the start of the next chip.

**Edit 2**

Looking back at my old notes, it was on a PET 2001 with 32K memory and the REM statements had to be added around the 8K region.

Comment: And how does a REM statement in source code defend against access to non-existent memory?

Comment: We had a 3032 at home and a Commodore 64. I do not recall ever seeing anything about a memory hole. I also read about and researched the PET extensively whilst writing my emulator and did not come across anything about a memory hole.

Comment: The contents of REM statements are ignored by BASIC when programs are run. This can be used to place what I guess you could consider a hole in which some binary data can go without it tripping up the BASIC interpreter. I know it was commonly used to store small chunks of machine language.

Comment: @Brian re *The contents of REM statements are ignored by BASIC when programs are run.*  But apparently not ignored when it comes to them occupying memory. How do they manage to occupy the 'gap' in memory?  How does the input statement get written to memory which it seems does not exist?  If it truly does not exist, why is there no machine error when the REM statements are entered?  How can BASIC read the statement to know it is a REM to be ignored?

Comment: I am saying the memory used in those REM statements might be considered/called 'gaps' by some. I do not think any hole/gap in memory itself exists.

Comment: An example of using machine language in a REM statement (in this case for a VIC-20): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHJeQlGrTpQ

Comment: The PET RAM was notoriously unreliable, could it have been a machine-specific fix for bad bits?

Comment: @dave The REM statements may have been a defense against BAD memory. BASIC lines are linked, so the whole REM-line will be skipped on execution, and during save/load it doesn't matter if the affected bad bits flip (or have flipped) and produce garbage.

Comment: @dirkt Sure, but that would be specific to a certain machine, and not a feature of 'Most Large Programs'. Using Occams Razor this looks more like an explanation imagined when trying to patch a program he didn't really understand.

Comment: @Raffzahn keep in mind that memory often plays tricks on us, and then "many programs I happened to see on this particular machine" becomes "most large programs".

Comment: @dirkt No sure by what logic. If it's just one machine, than those program must have been made all by that machines owner - who seems to know so little about then that he couldn't change them? Aren't that a bit to many assumption to support the 'bad memory' theory?

Comment: I recall a video about a dungeon-crawler game for the PET which had a bug which would cause a POKE that was supposed to update the screen to instead hit the wrong address which would corrupt part of the program.  The "fix" back in the day was to add some REM statements which could get clobbered without breaking anything else, but would be rendered unnecessary if the buggy line elsewhere in the program was changed.  I forget the details, though.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, this may be related to code overlays, where a new, task specific code segment is loaded from disk or tape to replace an existing one. This was a technique much more advertised for the PET than for any of the later models.

In order for this to work, the new segment has to exactly match the address range of the existing segment, otherwise, the link structure of the BASIC program (which is really a linked list, referencing the memory address of the respective next line) would be lost, and maybe any existing variable data (which follows immediately on top of the BASIC program in memory), as well. It would make sense to adjust for this by including REM statements, which would allow for minor modifications without a need to recreate all the other segments according to a new load address. (Mind that on the PET, all programs were loaded absolutely, just like with a secondary load address of "1" on the later 8-bit systems. Relative loading, i.e. the automatic relocation of BASIC programs, only became a thing with the VIC-20 and its different and also varying BASIC start address. So memory overlays may have been more "natural" to the PET environment. Moreover, PETs – apart from those with the very first ROM version – came with a built-in machine language monitor in ROM [dropped on later Commodore 8-bits to make room for color support], which would have facilitated saving dedicated RAM segments and made this technique more accessible.)

Anyways, the very fact of the removal of these REM statements leading to a corruption of these programs hints at self-modification by one mechanism or another. E.g., a short machine language routine may have been assembled from DATA statements into the locations reserved by a REM statement, which would inevitably result in memory corruption, if these statements would have been removed or changed in length.
(A reason for doing it this way may have been to avoid the Scylla and Charybdis of the growing variable stack on the one side of free memory and the growing string stack from the other, top side, without a need to adjust for varying memory configurations. Notably, this wouldn't have been a thing on the C64, which already came with a full memory complement, but would have been an issue on the PET, which came in configurations of 8K, 16K, or 32K [and, initially, just 4K] of RAM.)

***Edit**, regarding the edit:*

I may add, there is no way that multiple RAM chips may share the same address or may overlap in the address space.
The PET features a continuous memory space for RAM from $0000 up to 32K (the lower half the available 64K address space.) Screen memory is 1K at $8000 and ROM is from $C000 to $FFFF with a gap for IO at $E800–$EFFF. All PETs but the original PET 2001 also feature a ROM slot required vor BASIC 4 at $B000–$BFFF and slots for option ROMs at $9000-$AFFF, thus mapping the entire 64K.

PETs also perform a RAM check at startup to determine the available RAM (which is why you see $AA for any empty, but initialized RAM, while unconnected addresses typically show the high-byte of that address, which is a quirk of the 6502. The original PET 2001 may also show some noise added to the high-nibble of any unconnected addresses.)

(The 6502 is actually quite finicky with the data bus and it's quite difficult to implement bank switching. Which is why the 6510 introduced dedicated port registers at $0000 and $0001.)

Comment: Wellcome to RC.SE :)

Comment: I made it, finally… :-)

Comment: Told you, we'll get you one day :))

Comment: Got assimilated. Apparently not always a bad thing. :-)

Comment: The fact that unconnected addresses show the high byte of the address isn't really a 6502 quirk, but rather a result of a floating data bus staying near the voltage level to which it was last driven.  If one loads e.g. $FC and $FD with $12 and $34, respectively, and loads Y with $FF, and performs "LDA ($FC),Y", the last three memory operations would be fetchig $34 from address $FD, fetching whatever is on the bus (i.e. $34) from address $3411, and then fetching whatever is on the bus (still $34) from address $3511.

Comment: "there is no way that multiple RAM chips may share the same address" - well, they technically *can,* if the logic driving the CS pins is done badly. But that would result in much hilarity/angst.

Comment: @paxdiablo Of course, you can "piggy-back" multiple chips, thus connecting them to the same lines, but they will appear indiscriminately as a single unit, without any functional discrepancy to any other chips – it's just that memory at that address. If memory appears at multiple addresses, yes that's that, as well. But there should be a 1:1 relation between addresses and any signal source behind this, whatever this may be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems mostly like a combination of a certain software structure relaying on program layout, like for machine code/data storage, and an imagined explanation.

---

> Most largish programs written for the Commodore PET have a bunch of rem statements somewhere around the 8K or 16K area.

That would be completely new to me. Also, what means most? And which original PET (since you distinct it from 40/80xx) had more than 8 KiB?

> The normal comment is something to do with a hole in memory.

Maybe less off a hole than creating one.

> I remember PET programs crashing when I removed it.

That just means the program was sensitive about whats there - or location of other parts - as in using the REM lines as fixed address for machine programs and/or runtime data storage.

> What is this memory gap? Is it something like an address that has no memory?

No such thing with PETs or any 6502 commodore, except for the VIC20.

> The other possibility is an overlap, where the address of the end of one chip overlapped with the address of the start of the next chip.

Why on earth should anyone build a system faulty by design? Even less a company that price focused as Commodore.

Comment: "And which original PET (since you distinct it from 40/80xx) had more than 8 KiB?" Depends how you define "PET" but the 30xx series came in 16k and 32k versions. By that time, Commodore was calling them the CBM 3016 and CBM 3032 respectively, but everybody else called them "PET".

Comment: @JeremyP not in my memory.

Comment: @Raffzahn - maybe your memory has a gap?  ;-)

Comment: @Raffzahn My parents bought a 3016. We called it a PET. Everybody called it a PET except Commodore.

Comment: @JeremyP might be something local, as everyone I know called them CBM , or just 3016 - PET was strictly only about the chicklet one. (also, you're just repeating yourself :))

Comment: @Raffzahn I'm not just repeating myself. I'm giving you some context as to how I know everybody called them "PET".

Comment: @JeremyP Errm, what else to call a second comment _("We called it a PET. Everybody called it a PET except Commodore.")_ repeat a point already made in the first comment _("Commodore was calling them the CBM 3016 and CBM 3032 respectively, but everybody else called them "PET"")_ ? Cant see a difference. Of course now, in your third comment the relevant restriction was added _" I know everybody"_ whichis the important point, as it only relates to your bubble, not valid in a generic sense as made before.

Comment: @Raffzahn My second comment included "My parents bought a 3016. We called it a PET." Neither this quote nor anything like it appeared in my first comment. Therefore, I was not repeating myself.  You seem to have forgotten to put that bit in your quote, for some reason.

Comment: @JeremyP Err, are you saying those two quotes feature not the same content? But yeah, if it's very special about the computer your parents bought, tell me how that changes it to be more universal, less local? Just trying to understand your point?

Comment: @Raffzahn Well done. You've realised that two comments with different content are not repeating each other.

Comment: @JeremyP No, I didn't, as you didn't explain the difference to me. Both claim the same.

Comment: @Raffzahn You're just repeating yourself now.